# GetOverlappedResultEx will create a thread to process on or do I have to create and sync the threads?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

Trying to understand how this works... do I have to create various threads to take advantage of the functionality for GetOverlappedResultEx?  However why couldn't I just put GetOverlappedResult in a separate thread from the main thread to handle blocking of the IO and not interfere with main operations?

GetOverlappedResult function

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-getoverlappedresult

Retrieves the results of an overlapped operation on the specified file, named pipe, or communications device. To specify a timeout interval or wait on an alertable thread, use GetOverlappedResultEx.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-getoverlappedresultex

Retrieves the results of an overlapped operation on the specified file, named pipe, or communications device within the specified time-out interval. The calling thread can perform an alertable wait.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/alertable-i-o

Comment: You do it yourself.  But check out [I/O Completion Ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/i-o-completion-ports) to understand how to do this efficiently if you're looking at multiple async operations simultaneously on the same thread.  (Though it is probably better to experiment/learn without I/O Completion Ports first, just to understand what's going on, then add them into the mix later.)

Comment: `GetOverlappedResultEx` not create any threads but wait for I/O complete and return final status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You handle threads, for concurrency, yourself.

There are basically three ways to do it:

1. Having initiated an overlapped (i.e., async completion) I/O operation you do something else and then every once in awhile poll the handle to see if the overlapped operation has completed.  This is how you can use `GetOverlappedResult` looking for `STATUS_PENDING` to see if the operation isn't done yet.
2. You sit around waiting for an overlapped operation to complete.  But it's not as bad as that, because you can actually sit around waiting for any of a set of overlapped operations to complete.  As soon as any one completes you handle it, and then loop around to wait for the rest. Handling it, of course, may fire off *another* asynch operation, you add that handle to the list.  This is where you use `WaitForSingleObject{Ex}` or better `WaitForMultipleObjects{Ex}`.
3. You use I/O Completion ports.  Here you pass some handles to a kernel object called an I/O Completion port - this kernel object cleverly combines a thread pool (that it manages itself) with callbacks.  It is a very efficient way of dealing with multiple - in fact, very many - async operations in-flight simultaneously.  In these callbacks you can do whatever you want, including initiating more async operations and adding them to the same I/O Completion port.

There is also a fourth concept: alertable I/O, which executes a callback on an "APC" on your thread that initiated the I/O, provided your thread is in an "alertable" state - which means it is executing one or another of certain APIs that wait in the kernel.  But I've never used it, as it seems to have drawbacks (such as only working on the thread that initiated the I/O, and that the environment the callback environment runs in isn't as clear as it could be) and if you're going to go that far just figure out I/O Completion ports and use them.

Options #2 and #3 of course involve concurrent programming - so in both cases you have to make sure your callbacks are thread-safe with respect to your other threads.

There are plenty of examples of all these methods out there on the intertubes.

Comment: **3** have 2 sub-options - use `BindIoCompletionCallback` or `CreateThreadpoolIo`. internally it bind file to system managed iocp. as result not need create iocp by self and not need create thread pool, which pop packets from iocp. or possible do this yourself (create iocp and listen pool).

Comment: about *APC* completion - yes, of course apc called only in thread, which begin I/O. but callback environment absolute clear. and many win32 api have no way set apc callback. simply no parameter for this. despite internal native api of course always have such parameter. in some situation apc callbacks can be really useful and good solution

Comment: I have a very good experience with alertable I/O. It is sometimes just a good fit for the use case. It not only alleviates the limit of objects WaitForMultipleObjects can wait on, it is also comparitively easy to use, assuming one thread, because you do not need to deal with WaitForMultipleObjects API and determine which object got signalled via indices and so on.
Even asynchronous windows APIs don't actually return immediately; ReadFileEx for example can take milliseconds. If you can't have that, having a thread dedicated to it using alertable I/O makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Dico - interesting observation about alertable I/O (immediate return for async APIs that can return immediately - or at least quicker than the async variety.